# How to use concatenation operator in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, triggers, field

I wrote very simple trigger, that logs update of one table in another. And I need to keep previous state of main entry in that history table.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_history 
    AFTER UPDATE ON cars WHEN old.id == new.id 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO history (track_car, entry_updated, previous_state) 
        VALUES (new.id, 
                datetime('now','localtime'), 
                old.plate || ';' || 
                old.brand || ';' || 
                old.model || ';' || 
                old.year || ';' || 
                old.color || ';' || 
                old.VIN || ';' || 
                old.power  || ';' || 
                old.body);
```

Actually, the trigger works. But `previous_state` field remains null every time I run UPDATE query.

As I am new to SQL/SQLite I have no idea why it is so. Maybe I need to coerce all that `old.xxx` fields to TEXT explicitly? But I haven't find smth about it in SQLite Documentation.

Comment: If any field is `NULL`, then result of concatenation using `||` is NULL

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda, okay, that answers my question. But how do I concatenate ignoring NULL?

Comment: Using `COALESCE(old.plate, '<NULL>')` the replacement value should match column data type

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda, thank you, man!